# Realtime Profile Preview on the Same Page as the Registration Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am creating a multi-step registration form (most likely with Jquery)which previews the user's selections into a complete profile preview right below the form. For example, if the user wrote a tagline and clicks away from the text field, then the preview will automatically update.

How can I do this with Javascript? Do I need any other languages?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I would suggest looking for some tutorials on the subject, it will help your learning. Your question is a bit too general as it stands. SO works best when you show what you have tried so far, and explain the specific error or problem you are facing. Good luck...

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I'm actually new to web dev so I am also asking for a comprehensive starting point too sorry lol.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with jQuery. You have to select your target html element with jQuery.

```js
$('#text').on('change', function(){
  var textValue = $(this).val();
  $('.result').html(textValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" name="name" />  
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple example that do what you want.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>Form</h1>
  <form role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control bind" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="tagline">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="tagline" class="form-control bind" id="tagline" placeholder="Enter tagline">
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
   </label>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>Profile</h1>
  <h1 id="bind-name"></h1>
  <h4 id="bind-tagline"></h4>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.bind').on('change', function(){
   $this = $(this);
   element_name = $this.attr('name');
   $('#bind-'+element_name).html($this.val());
});
```

you can check it here: 
http://www.bootply.com/h7CKrnNtWw